# Redirecting attacker to domain, but vulnerability in URL Rewrite rule still present. How to secure my local host?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

In IIS, I used the URL Rewrite to  create a rule that redirects my two sites (site1.domain.com) back to my domain should an attacker attempt to direct users to a false site using my domain name. Under local host, I have Default Web Site, Home, Mysite, and SharePoint Web Services. The rules are created under Home and Mysite. However, my vulnerability assessment server is still populating the vulnerability in this configuration. When I place the rule at the top under local host, the vulnerability is removed, but none of the users can access the sites. I’m assuming that I need to place a rule under the default web site and sharepoint web services, but the bindings are not using a domain name. They are using local host and a port. Can anyone tell me what the rule would look like to protect local host from host header vulnerabilities.

I have tried placing the rule under the local host, however users are unable to access the sites when the rule is enabled.

Comment: If you don't want to share more of your setup due to factors like confidentiality, you should hire a security consultant, not posting around. A "vulnerability"? What kind of vulnerability? "I need to place a rule", but then what exactly is the rule you wrote?

Comment: Hi Lex. The vulnerability is HTTP Host Header Value Reflection and I explained the rule I wrote in the first sentence; my apologies if that wasn't enough information as this was my first post. I was only trying to simplify the question. Last, and this for everyone out there, it doesn't matter if it's your personal computer or you work for some Fortune 500 company, don't post your Personal Identifiable Information (PII) or sensitive information on public sites such as this one; no matter how much someone tries to push you in to doing so. Techs will understand site1 vs. your actual site name.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want useful advice, please provide detailed and specific information.**

I roughly see what you mean. The "**Request Blocking**" rule template can be used to generate a rule that blocks incoming requests based on various criteria. Requests can be blocked based on certain pattern within URL path or based on certain value in one of the request headers.
For detailed steps, you can refer to the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template.

Comment: That was very helpful. The vulnerability is HTTP Host Header Value Reflection and it's capable of manipulating host headers like the following: http://127.0.0.1/bad_page.html   While I did implement the request blocking rule on the default web site and SharePoint Web Services, the vulnerability unfortunately still populated and was able to create a false site after / on the localhost.

Comment: Refer to this support blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/host-header-vulnerability/ba-p/1031958.

Comment: URL Rewrite Rule, Port 80

1. Open IIS and click site folder
2. Select URL Rewrite
3. "Actions", Add Rule
4. "Blank Rule"
5. Name: URL Mismatch
6. “Requested URL”, Matches the Pattern
7. “Using”, Regular Expressions
8. “Pattern”, (.*)
9. Select Conditions
10. Select Add
11. “Condition input”, {HTTP_HOST}
12. “Check if input string:”, Does Not Match the Pattern
13. “Pattern”, ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*example\.com$
14. OK
15. “Action” and “Action type:”, Redirect
16. “Action Properties” and “Rewrite URL”, https://example.com
17. “Actions”, select Apply
18. Verify access and rescan

Comment: I used the instruction in my previous comment which works to remove the vulnerability; verified using our assessment server. However, I can no longer access the site unless I disable the rule. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I tested the rewrite rule mentioned in the documentation on my site, and the site can be accessed normally. You can enable url rewrite rules and enable FRT to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Solution: Concerning SharePoint, I found the fix within the Default Website folder only by creating the URL Rewrite Rule described above, but instead of using "example\.com" in the pattern above, replace that with the server name: ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*servername$